# How to add data to a model dynamically in qml?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

i am building a music player app where i need to load the song data based on the album name.
I have initialised my model by passing the model object to qml like this in main.cpp file

```
      albumSongs globalSongListModel;
      ctxt->setContextProperty("globalSongListModel", &globalSongListModel);
```

in this class albumSongs i have the following properties

```
Q_PROPERTY(QString songName READ songName CONSTANT)
Q_PROPERTY(QString songFileUrl READ songFileUrl CONSTANT)
Q_PROPERTY(QString songDuration READ songDuration CONSTANT)
```

I have a public slot in the albumSongs class which gets the data from the qml event

```
public slots:
    QList<QObject*> getSongListByAlbumName(QString albumName){
        dbHelper dbh;
        QList<QObject*> songList;
        dbh.loadDataByAlbumName(albumName, songList);
        return songList;

    }
```

the loadDataByAlbumName() function is declared in dbhelper class as follows

```
void dbHelper::loadDataByAlbumName(QString albumName, QList<QObject*>& songList) {
    QString query = "SELECT " + this->LI_DATA_TABLE_COLUMN_ONE + "," + this->LI_DATA_TABLE_COLUMN_TWO + "," + this->LI_DATA_TABLE_COLUMN_NINE +  " FROM " + this->LI_DATA_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + this->LI_DATA_TABLE_COLUMN_THREE + "=?";
    QSqlQuery sql;
    sql.prepare(query);
    sql.bindValue(0, albumName);
    sql.exec();
    while (sql.next()) {
        QString songName = sql.value(0).toString();
        QString songUrl = sql.value(1).toString();
        QString songDuration = sql.value(2).toString();
        songList.append(new albumSongs(songName, songUrl, songDuration));
    }
}
```

i can successfully load the data from db to the QListsongList 
But when i try to use it in the qml file like this

```
ListView {
    id: song_list_view
    width: 180; height: 200
    anchors.top: name.bottom;
    anchors.topMargin: 30
    delegate: Text {
        text: songName + " " + songFileUrl
    }




}
```

i get the error in delegate column stating that songName is not defined.

I have been setting this model on mouse enter event like this

```
  onEntered: {
            song_list_view.model = globalSongListModel.getSongListByAlbumName(globalName)

        }
```

Is this correct way of doing this task? What should i do to resolve the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have a bad design: how an albumSongs has a songName, songFileUrl and songDuration ?, in fact you must have a class that stores the data of a Song and another class manager that has the slot that returns the list.

Going to the problem, when the model is a list then you must use `modelData` to access each item, but you still can not access the properties because QML does not know that class so you must register it with `qmlRegisterUncreatableType()` so that you can access the properties but not create objects of that class in QML:

```
class Song : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString songName READ songName CONSTANT)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString songFileUrl READ songFileUrl CONSTANT)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString songDuration READ songDuration CONSTANT)
public:
    explicit Song(const QString & songName="",
                  const QString & songFileUrl="",
                  const QString & songDuration="",
                  QObject *parent = nullptr):
        QObject(parent),
        m_songName(songName),
        m_songFileUrl(songFileUrl),
        m_songDuration(songDuration)
    {}
    QString songName() const{
        return m_songName;
    }

    QString songFileUrl() const{
        return  m_songFileUrl;
    }
    QString songDuration() const{
        return m_songDuration;
    }

private:
    QString m_songName;
    QString m_songFileUrl;
    QString m_songDuration;
};

class SongManager: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit SongManager(QObject *parent=nullptr):
        QObject(parent)
    {}
public slots:
    static QList<QObject*> getSongListByAlbumName(const QString & name){
        QList<QObject*> songList;
        dbHelper dbh;
        dbh.loadDataByAlbumName(albumName, songList);
        return songList;
    }
};
```

**main.cpp**

```
// ...
qmlRegisterUncreatableType<Song>("Songs", 1, 0, "Song", "Error class uncreatable");
// ...
SongManager manager;
ctxt->setContextProperty("manager", &manager);
// ...
```

***.qml**

```
// ...
import Songs 1.0
// ...
ListView {
    id: song_list_view
    width: 180; height: 200
    anchors.top: name.bottom;
    anchors.topMargin: 30
    delegate: Text {
        text: modelData.songName + " " + modelData.songFileUrl
    }
}
// ...
onEntered: song_list_view.model = manager.getSongListByAlbumName(globalName)
```

Comment: I am just curious to know why this is a bad design, can you please help me to realise it?

Comment: @NaveenKingmaker Each class defines a concept and a behavior, in your case that defines the class albumSongs, according to the name it tells me that it is a collection of songs, and then why that collection only has a name, a url and a duration of only one song? Do not you think it's contradictory? In my proposal it states that there must be a class that defines a single song and another class that defines a class that provides the song collections.

Comment: Yeah, i got it now, single responsibility principle.

Comment: is loading the song based on mouse entered event is a correct way?

Comment: @NaveenKingmaker That depends on the user experience you want to propose :-). Finally the comments serve to discuss the specific problem, that is, the question of the post or my answer, not on other topics. :-)